# Need a tutorial for Installing Flash CS5 on Eclipse for Android development

Tags: android, eclipse, flash, flash-cs5

I am looking for a step by step clean tutorial for installing flash CS5 on eclipse. I want to make an android application using Flash CS5, Adobe Air and Eclipse.
I have been trying stuff on youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBs5tehQ5qk

and tutorial:

http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/inspire/august2010/articles/article1/index.html

but they do not seem to make sense.

Please put some light on it

Comment: Search on google for tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistaking eclipse and FlashBuilder CS5 (which is built on top of Eclipse).

It's all one thing... just head over to Adobe and download Flash Builder.  It'll all be downhill from there! :)

You can get a free 30 day trial to see if you want to shell out the big bucks for the license.

You can, of course, build Android apps in AIR, without Flash Builder, in regular Flash... in that case, there's no Eclipse... you'll just work in the Flash IDE.  I would recommend the Flash Builder since you're already watching tutorials on how to use that, and it seems to be what you're after.

Comment: you're welcome! Don't hesitate to upvote/and or declare my answer the correct one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need eclipse. Flash CS5.5 will publish an android APK file. Also you can use FlashDevelop to do the same and it is free.
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page
Flash Develop is an IDE. You will be coding actionscript, not java, and you can compile to a java apk file using the included batch files.

Comment: I used to think stupidly that Ecilpse can be used by installing a plugin for flash CS5 and Air to develop android. But thanks alot for showing me the light. I clicking the link though. Brillian!